# SCLAlertView Add Button Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, objective-c-blocks, target

I am having an issue with the CocoaPod SCLAlertView.

For some reason, the "addButton" with an action block functionality does not work.  When the "Log Out" button in the SCLAlertView is tapped, the code for it in the action block does not execute ("log out button tapped" never prints and the code in the block doesn't execute).  However, it does in my other app with the exact same code.

The code that does not work is here:

[image]

Here is the Podfile for the app where SCLAlertView addButton DOES NOT WORK:

[image]

Here is the Podfile for the app where SCLAlertView DOES WORK:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images when you can post the actual text of the file. It's easier to read and easier to reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should've realized this was the issue.  The CocoaPod version for SCLAlertView that works with this was 0.8.2 and mine was stuck at 0.8.1 but I didn't realize it.  Just had to specify that as the version of the pod with the following and it worked:

pod 'SCLAlertView-Objective-C', '~> 0.8.2'